# Ajax call to Struts2 action producing javax.xml.transform.TransformerException

Tags: xml, ajax, jquery, struts2

I'm trying to write a small example of calling a Struts2 action from Ajax and getting data back using XML. When the call executes, I get a `javax.xml.transform.TransformerException` (shown below). Eventually, I want to get the name property out of the data XML that comes back from the Ajax call.

I'm probably missing something simple here but I'm at a loss as to what's missing.

My action from struts.xml:

```
<action name="AjaxFormSubmit" class="test.FormSubmit" >
    <result type="xslt">
        <param name="exposedValue">fName</param>
    </result>
</action>
```

Javascript:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "AjaxFormSubmit.action",
    error: function( data )
    {
        alert( "error" );
        alert( data );
    },
    success: function( data )
    {
        alert( "success" );
        alert( data );
    }
});
```

My action class:

```
public class FormSubmit extends ActionSupport {

    public FormSubmit()
    {
        System.out.println( "in FormSubmit constructor" );
    }

    private String fName;

    public String getFName() {
        return fName;
    }

    public void setFName(String fName) {
        System.out.println( "setting fName: " + fName );
        this.fName = fName;
    }

    public String execute() throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println( "in execute" );

        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

The exception:

```
Aug 9, 2012 1:32:20 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger error
SEVERE: Unable to render XSLT Template, 'null'
Error transforming result - [unknown location]
    at org.apache.struts2.views.xslt.XSLTResult$1.error(XSLTResult.java:351)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.postErrorToListener(TransformerImpl.java:788)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:731)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:336)
    at org.apache.struts2.views.xslt.XSLTResult.execute(XSLTResult.java:392)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:374)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:278)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:176)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:211)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:211)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:190)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:90)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:243)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:176)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:192)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:187)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:511)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: Operation not supported.
    ... 68 more
```

Answer (score 0):

What's missing is the XSL template, as indicated by the error:

```
SEVERE: Unable to render XSLT Template, 'null'
```

The ["xslt" result type docs](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/xsl-result.html) state a "location" param defines the template.

Do you actually want an XSL result, or just XML? Are you really transforming it?

Comment: I actually want XML but what I've read so far about XSLTResult is that you should use that if you want straight XML and its default behavior is to serialize the entire bean as XML and no transform is necessary.

Comment: @ChrisWilliams Could be; I'm not aware of that though--where did you read that? It could have changed, too, although I have no idea what version of S2 you're using. In any case, that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think that an implementation of `XSLTResult` was changed and parameter `location` is now required.

But you still can view generated XML when you use XSL file below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
        <xsl:template match="/">
            <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, will help you in Struts 2.0.14 with jsonplugin-0.32.jar. it worked for me.

struts.xml:

```
<struts>
     <package name="example" extends="json-default">
        <action name="HelloWorld" class="example.HelloWorld"  >
            <result type="json" />
        </action>
              <action name="HelloWorld1" class="example.HelloWorld"  >
            <result name="success" >example/HelloWorld.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

action class Helloworld.java:

```
package prabhakar;

import glb.DB;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Prabhakar
 */
public class HelloWorld  {


    private List<StateMaster> stateList= new ArrayList<StateMaster>();
    private List<RegnMaster> regnList= new ArrayList<StateMaster>();

    private Integer stateId;
    public Integer getStateId()
    {
    return this.stateId;
    }
    public void setStateId(Integer stateId)
    {
    this.stateId=stateId;
    }
    public List<StateMaster> getStateList() {
        return stateList;
    }

    public void setStateList(List<StateMaster> stateList) {
        this.stateList = stateList;
    }
     public void setRegnList(List<RegnMaster> regnList) {
        this.regnList = regnList;
    }
    public List<RegnMaster> getRegnList() {
        return regnList;
    }

    public String execute() throws Exception {

        stateList=DB.getStateData()//
        if(stateId !=null)
          {
         regnList=DB.getRegnByStateId(stateId);
          }

        //setMessage(getText(MESSAGE));
        return "success";
    }

    /**
     * Provide default valuie for Message property.
     */

}
```

You can directly call HelloWorld.action to view the JSON data or else you can bind the JSON data to a form element below.

JSP page HelloWorld.jsp:

```
  /*
     Prabhakar
  */

<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>

<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<script>
<%@include file="../js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"%>
</script>
    <html>

<!-- JavaScript Plugins -->
  <script>
       function getLoad(){


       var stateId = $('#state').val();

$.getJSON('HelloWorld.action', {'stateId': stateId},
    function(data) {

           var divisionList = (data.regnList);

                var options = $("#regn");
                options.find('option')
    .remove()
    .end();
     options.append($("<option />").val("-1").text("--Select--"));
$.each(divisionList, function() {

    options.append($("<option />").val(this.regnId).text(this.regnName));
});
    }
);}
   </script>

<!-- jQuery-UI Dependent Scripts -->

    <body>
        State List <s:select name="stateId" list="stateList" id="state" listKey="stateId" onchange="getLoad()" listValue="stateName" headerKey="0" headerValue="--select--" />
        Regn List <s:select name="regnId"  list="regnList" listKey="regnId" id="regn" listValue="regnName" headerKey="0" headerValue="--select--" />
    </body>
</html>
```

:) :)